# Can I speed up my text file writing by using memory first?

Tags: c++, performance

Here is my code in C++
I am trying to speed it up if possible.
How do I write to memory then dump the whole file to "Primes List.txt" at the end?
Thanks if you can help at all.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\n\n\n     Calculating all Prime Numbers up to 82,000,000";
    cout << "\n\n     You will have to give me exactly a minute! ...";
    cout << "\n\n     ";
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Primes List.txt");
    myfile << "2\n";
    vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    for (int i = 3; i < 82000000; i++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < primes.size() && primes[j] * primes[j] <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % primes[j] == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime)
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
            myfile << i << "\n";
         }
     }
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    myfile << "\n Elapsed Time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds\n";
    cout << "Elapsed Time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds\n\n\n";
    myfile.close();
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I'm running this on quite a beast of a PC and would expect it to run faster.

Comment: Your streams are buffered, so they already use memory.

Comment: _"and would expect it to run faster"_ compared to what exactly??

Comment: Right now you're measuring everything all together. If you restructure things you could measure the generation and writing the file separately, then if you changed how you write you could tell if it made a difference.

Comment: Start by making sure you are building your code with compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: Just remove all the file writing code. You might be surprised to learn that your program's execution time hardly changes.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream myfile; myfile.open("Primes List.txt");` to `ofstream myfile("Primes List.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `myfile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Question to the close voters: what "details or clarity" do you want? The question is how to speed up the code, and the comments indicate that most readers of the question understand exactly what's being asked.

Comment: Are you using `-O2` or `-O3`?

Comment: You'll get the biggest gains from optimizing your prime-generating algorithm. One immediate gain would be to stop checking if the even numbers between 4 and 82,000,000 are prime. To your immediate question: You're already building up `primes` in memory, you're just also writing to the file as you go. You could simply build up `primes` in one loop, and then use a second loop to write `primes` to file afterward. That'd also make it easier to time the two steps separately.

Comment: On my crufty 7 year old geriatric machine, using `-O3`, the algorithm is taking 45.4811 seconds, and the I/O is taking 1.13218 seconds.  Without optimization the algorithm+I/O combined was taking 128.836 seconds.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? Did you find it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As multiple commenters noted, the first issue is to speed up the prime generation. The following code 1) uses a bitmap for the sieve which greatly reduces the required memory and 2) only checks numbers that are `+/-1 mod 6`.

This is fastest sieve algorithm of which I know. On my machine it only took 108ms to cover up to 82M. Sieving the odds was 180ms and I didn't have enough patience to measure the canonical sieve algorithm.

### Sample Code

```cpp
auto sieve_mod6_prime_seq(int max = int{1} << 20) {
    std::vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    primes.push_back(3);

    auto max_index = max / 3;
    auto bits_per = sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    auto nwords = (bits_per + max_index - 1) / bits_per;
    std::vector<uint64_t> words(nwords);

    words[0] |= 1;
    size_t wdx = 0;
    while (wdx < nwords) {
        auto b = std::countr_one(words[wdx]);
        auto p = 3 * (64 * wdx + b) + 1 + (b bitand 1);
        if (b < 64 and p < max) {
            primes.push_back(p);

            for (auto j = p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }

            for (auto j = 5 * p; j < max; j += 6 * p) {
                auto idx = j / 3;
                auto jdx = idx / 64;
                auto jmask = uint64_t{1} << (idx % 64);
                words[jdx] |= jmask;
            }
        }
        else {
            ++wdx;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

For `C++` versions without `std::countr_one` available, here is an implementation.

```cpp
// If we are using gcc or clang, using the compiler builtin.
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)

int countr_one(unsigned int n) {
    return ~n == 0 ? (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT) : __builtin_ctz(~n);
}

int countr_one(unsigned long int n) {
    return ~n == 0 ? (sizeof(unsigned long int) * CHAR_BIT) : __builtin_ctzl(~n);
}

int countr_one(unsigned long long int n) {
    return ~n == 0 ? (sizeof(unsigned long long int) * CHAR_BIT) : __builtin_ctzll(~n);
}

// Otherwise, a standards compliant implementation
#else

int countr_one(uint32_t n) {
    n = ~n & (n+1);   // this gives a 1 to the left of the trailing 1's
    n--;              // this gets us just the trailing 1's that need counting
    n = (n & 0x55555555) + ((n>>1) & 0x55555555);  // 2 bit sums of 1 bit numbers
    n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n>>2) & 0x33333333);  // 4 bit sums of 2 bit numbers
    n = (n & 0x0f0f0f0f) + ((n>>4) & 0x0f0f0f0f);  // 8 bit sums of 4 bit numbers
    n = (n & 0x00ff00ff) + ((n>>8) & 0x00ff00ff);  // 16 bit sums of 8 bit numbers
    n = (n & 0x0000ffff) + ((n>>16) & 0x0000ffff); // sum of 16 bit numbers
    return n;
}

int countr_one(uint64_t n) {
    n = ~n & (n+1);
    n--;
    n = (n & 0x5555555555555555ul) + ((n>>1) & 0x5555555555555555ul);
    n = (n & 0x3333333333333333ul) + ((n>>2) & 0x3333333333333333ul);
    n = (n & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0ful) + ((n>>4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0ful);
    n = (n & 0x00ff00ff00ff00fful) + ((n>>8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00fful);
    n = (n & 0x0000ffff0000fffful) + ((n>>16) & 0x0000ffff0000fffful);
    n = (n & 0x00000000fffffffful) + ((n>>32) & 0x00000000fffffffful);
    return n;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Very useful comments on this especially this one - thanks - Trevor

Comment: Hi there - I have an error on auto b = std::countr_one(words[wdx]); namespace "std" has no member "countr_one - countr_one is not a member of 'std' - I feel I'm close but cannot get past this error - thanks for any help you can give? Trev

Comment: That is this [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_one). Did you include `bit`? It is a `C++20` library feature, so it may not be available depending on what version of the standard library you are using. I can update my answer with an implementation of `std::countr_one` that works for earlier versions of `C++` if needed.

Comment: #include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 64bit 17.6.1 and did some reading about C++20 which I have swapped to in the PrimeSieve.cpp Properties as per instructions - still get two Errors: 
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) PrimesSieve  Programs\PrimesSieve\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1 
and Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals PrimesSieve Programs\PrimesSieve\x64\Debug\PrimesSieve.exe 1 
As you can tell - I'm a newbie and couldn't implement the code you gave me above - thanks - Trevor